# CSV file download via CDN but became a String?

Tags: html, csv, download, safari, cdn

I have stored a CSV file in a CDN and using the link in Chrome, you can download the file as usual. However I have tried downloading the same file using Safari and it opens up as a string, does anyone know why?

Safari Output:

> First Name,Last Name,Address 1,Address 2,town,Postcode,GIFT,PERSONAL,(click on cells to view instructions) 
>   EXAMPLE: The miller,Family,1 Asturias,Ocean Village,Southampton,SO143HT,Laura Ashley Cushions,"They will look great in our new lounge, we look forward to seeing you at Christmas. ",

Here is my CSV file via CDN:

https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0931/3232/files/Example_wedding_Upload_file_s.csv?1873781383088988082

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set "Content-Disposition: attachment" header for CSV extension. This will solve your problem.